# Unable to delete SOLR entry using curl

Tags: php, curl, solr

Hi I am trying to delete a specific solr line(document).

I followed several blogs and reached here.

When I type in

```
http://ip_addresss:8983/solr/master/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3Eitem_id:58987825%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true
```

in my browser, it works like a charm.

However if I try to use it via curl, its not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are placing the url inside quote (`""`), otherwise it will break at `&` character.

Make sure you are using an user-agent so that curl doesn't send default `User-Agent: curl/7.40.0`

So here it is something like below:

```
curl -A "Opera" "http://<ip addresss>:8983/solr/master/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3Eitem_id:58987825%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true"
```

Comment: Yup. That's the issue. Can't believe I overlooked it. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can. Thank you.